# Bulk convert a music collection with a mix of lossless and lossy formats

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, music, flac

I have a large-ish collection of music files, most of which are flac, some mp3 and other lossy formats. I want to create a copy of the whole collection in mp3.

The problem that I have is that when converting the files the audio converters that I have tried will also re-encode the files that were originally mp3, leading to a degradation of quality.

Is there a convenient way to copy the whole collection, whilst converting the flac files to mp3 but leaving the mp3 files alone (just copying them)?

Comment: What are your scripting skills like? The easiest way might be to write something which finds all the music files, ignores the mp3s and throws the rest through ffmpeg (or your audio converter of choice).

Comment: I like TAC for this, you can filter the music collection to only show FLAC files, then select all, then convert, not free though.....https://filehippo.com/download_total_audio_converter/

Comment: [flac2all](https://github.com/ZivaVatra/flac2all)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes brute force methods are easier than fancy ones:

1. Create a copy and then delete all the flac files in the copy.
2. Create a second copy where everything is re-encoded.
3. Copy the first copy onto the second overwriting the re-encoded mp3s with the original ones.